# Why I am experiencing this strange behavior using SimpleDateFormat to format a string representing a TimeStamp?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am finding some problem to generate a **String** representing a propper **time stamp** in Java.

So I have done in the following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
String timeStamp = DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
```

The problem is that I obtain the following wrong result: **'2016-06-23 12:25:85'**

The problem is related to the last digis (**85**) that should represent the seconds. But as you can see it is not a correct value for the second because the correct maximum value for the second in a minute is 60 and not 85

Why I obatin this strange behavior? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue and obtain the correct value for the seconds?

Comment: Please edit the Question to show your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper case S is for milliseconds. Use lower case s instead.

Answer (score 2):

SS represents Millisecond and ss represents seconds. Use yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 2):

This is because `SS` means **milliseconds** and not seconds, try with `ss`.

Take a look to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation.